# Please advice about security issue when using bitbucket

Tags: wordpress

I am new and I am not sure if this is a place to ask this question.
I developed a web site alone using wordpress framework.
Now, I got a guy who I don't know much to join me to develop the site. We live in different countries and we decide to use Bitbucket for code management.
I do not have any experiences in team working, Bitbucket.

My concerns are: 
1. Do I need to upload both source code and database to Bitbucket?

2. Do you think he will just take all the source code and database and make his own website and become my competitor?
3. What should I be careful when working in a team? I mean sharing code.

I know maybe I am quite small-minded. I am worried about security problems.
But definitely, I need to have someone to work with me to develop the site.

Please advice and write any sources that are useful for this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Wordpress, but the concept still applies:

1. Source code: yes. Database: no, only the database schema/ SQL scripts to recreate it.
2. Depends on his ethics. You should reach an agreement with him that guarantees that he won't do so, by writing a contract for example.
3. Take the following into consideration: coding standards, conventions are followed in naming variables, pages, urls, etc, repository privacy is set correctly, repository privileges are distributed to enable the contributors to do only what they're supposed to do.

I'll leave the rest to you and other fellows on this website to figure out depending on your experience :)

Comment: do you know any template for web system developer contract?

Comment: There is a lot of templates, just google them and find what fits you most. The problem is that everyone creates his own contract depending on his needs, which are different from a company/website/organization to another.

Comment: @Mike found what you wanted?